# Highcharts Overlapping bar with single Legends repeats

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have a functionality where I have to show the actual value and assumed value for a year as a bar. The actual bar should be inside the assumed value bar. The case is like there are list of categories which will be in legends as well in categories  (where as in usual examples  it will be different ones), (i.e) x axis will be numbers, y axis will be a list of categories will will come in legend as well.  There should be one legend for each category , while on toggling the legend both the actual value and assumed value should toggle
Can anyone help on this?

```
Inputs are 
<input type="hidden" id="lineSeries" value='[{"name":"Line Name","data":["EXPENSES","AMORTIZATION"],"value":0.0,"type":"","color":""}]'>
<input type="hidden" id="lineValueSeries" value='[{"name":"EXPENSES","data":["55"],"value":0.0,"type":"bar","color":""},{"name":"AMORTIZATION","data":["65"],"value":0.0,"type":"bar","color":""}]'>
<input type="hidden" id="lineAssumedSeries" value='[{"name":"EXPENSES","data":["70"],"value":0.0,"type":"bar","color":""},{"name":"AMORTIZATION","data":["85"],"value":0.0,"type":"bar","color":""}]'>

and chart is parsed like

var lineSeriesChart;



var options = {
chart: {
                renderTo: 'LineItemContainer',
                marginTop: 40,
                marginBottom: 80,
                width: 1100,
                //height: length * 23,  // 25px per data item plus top and bottom margins
                //height: 500,
                backgroundColor: null
},
title: {
                align:'center',
                                useHTML: true,
                style: {
fontSize:'14px',
fontFamily:'Verdana, sans-serif',
color:'#000000'
},
                text: '<B>Financial - Cost Breakup </B>'
                },
xAxis: {
                                categories: [],
                                labels: {
style: {
fontSize: '9px',
fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                                //fontWeight:'Bold'
}
},
tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
                },
yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
align:'middle',
                                text:'Cost',
style: {
fontSize:'10px',
color:'#000000',
fontFamily:'Verdana, sans-serif',
fontWeight:'Bold'
}
},
                                  lineWidth: 1,
                                  offset:2
                },
tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',

                crosshairs: false
                },
               exporting: {
buttons: { 
contextButtons: {
enabled: false,
menuItems: null
}
},enabled: false
}, credits: {
position: {
align: 'right'
},
                style: {
                                color: '#3E576F'
                },
                useHTML: true,
                text : ''</h3>'
},
legend: {
                enabled:true,
                borderWidth: 1,
    itemMarginTop: 2,
                itemMarginBottom: 2,
                width:220,
                itemWidth: 50,
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                style: {
fontSize:'9px',
color:'#000000',
fontFamily:'Verdana, sans-serif'
},
itemStyle: {
color:'#000000',
fontSize:'9px',
fontFamily:'Verdana, sans-serif'
}
},
plotOptions: {
column: {
    stacking: 'normal'
},
series:{


}               
},
series: []
};

    var lineSeries = eval( "("+document.getElementById('lineSeries').value+")") ;    

    var lineValueSeries = eval("("+document.getElementById('lineValueSeries').value+")") ;

        for(var i=0;i<=lineSeries.length-1;i++){
                var item = lineSeries[i];
                for(var j=0;j<=item.data.length-1;j++){
                                options.xAxis.categories.push(item.data[j]);
                                var series = {
                                                                data: []
                                                };
                                for(var k = 0; k <= lineValueSeries.length-1; k++){


                                                if(j == k){
                                                                var itemValue = lineValueSeries[k];
                                                                series.name = itemValue.name;
                                                                series.type =  itemValue.type;
                                                                series.data.push(parseInt(itemValue.data));
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                                series.data.push(parseInt(0));
                                                }
                                }
                                options.series.push(series);
                }
}              


lineSeriesChart =  new Highcharts.Chart(options);
lineSeriesChart.credits.hide();
```

Comment: JSFIDDLE:- http://jsfiddle.net/cindrella_agi/M6JgF/

Comment: I see only two bars in your example, shouldn't be there four of them? You can add more series, and use `linkedTo` option, so two series will be bind to one legend item. Will that resolve your issue?

Comment: thanked that helped. is there a way to give specified x and y position for each bar in a category (dynamically setting the position of the bar)

Comment: Sure, just set x and y.. ;) See supported [data formats](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data) - second or third point suit you probably the most.